# Use googlescript api in html

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an html file bound to a google spreadsheet that creates a small gui. There are buttons on the gui, and I want to buttons to do things that involve the spreadsheet, so I want to make calls to things like SpreadsheetApp.

For example, just so that I understand how to properly do this, let's say I want to just change one cell in a spread sheet, or log a value to the logger. Here is the html file that is served.

```
<div>
<P>Select an option below</P>
<script type="text/javascript">
Logger.log("in html");
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 14).setValue('In HTML');
</script>
</div>
```

Let's assume this is the googlescript that serves the html

```
function openDialog() {
 var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('TeacherView')
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
 SpreadsheetApp.getActive().show(html);

}
```

When the html file runs, shouldn't I see the range in the spreadsheet change values? Or see the logger log a value? Am I misunderstanding how the combination of the scripts and html work?

Sort of new to creating html/javascript things together, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use:

```
google.script.run.nameOfServerFunction()
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run

You can't use the Apps Script Services directly in a script tag in HTML.

```
<div>
<P>Select an option below</P>
<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log("in html");

  function onSuccess(argReturnValue) {
    alert('Success ' + argReturnValue);
  }

  var dataToPassToServer = get your data;

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
    .fncMyGsScriptFunctionNameHere(dataToPassToServer);

</script>
</div>
```

### Code.gs

```
function fncMyGsScriptFunctionNameHere(argDataPassedInHere) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 14).setValue(argDataPassedInHere);
};
```